# Could microfiber shedding be slashed by using a proper detergent?

Tags: plastic

Is this a real thing or just greenwashing? This problem of microplastic seemed so huge it's hard to believe you could make such an enormous dent in it just using a right detergent

> Offering consumers a simple solution, Zara just launched the first laundry detergent designed to minimize microfiber shedding during washing. Developed in collaboration with BASF Home Care and I&I Solutions Europe, the liquid detergent is said to reduce microfiber release by **up to 80%**, depending on the type of fabric and how it's washed. Laboratory testing also found that the formula is suitable for washing at low temperatures (down to 20°C), decreasing energy consumption.

*(from [Trendwatching](https://www.trendwatching.com/innovation-of-the-day/new-laundry-detergent-by-zara-reduces-microfiber-shedding-by-up-to-80-percent?utm_campaign=FTU%20Weekly%20&utm_medium=email&_hsmi=238901472&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-_kkeiPLlkYOduM8Hy1TdJSGJ9OJf2XWJ5FU7jTZKYyCfOt2KYOEncIKS5FrVDh4IE5oIs9YhMfidFhMKWI0_RzO6PSgA&utm_content=238852836&utm_source=hs_email))*

Comment: "Up to 80%" doesn't really say anything. Such a figure is achieved under ideal circumstances which may not be realistic. The question is how much microfibre release will be reduced by the average consumer continuing their otherwise normal washing pattern.

Comment: I've read in a science magazine (will try to find link) that washing with cold water and line drying IE not in tumble dryer are the two most important ways of reducing microfiber shedding.

Comment: @MocBird yes, though cold cycles often run for longer - more soaking and more agitation, which somewhat offsets this benefit of washing cold